# Getting output from Python script in Python tests

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

I've got a simple python script in file 'bin/test':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

PROGRAM_NAME        = "name"
PROGRAM_VERSION     = "0.0.1"
PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "desc"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=PROGRAM_NAME, description=PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION)
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s ' + PROGRAM_VERSION)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I run it with the `--version` param, or `--help`, it prints everything OK:

```
$ bin/test --version
name 0.0.1

$ bin/test --help
usage: name [-h] [--version]

desc

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --version   show program's version number and exit
```

When I run the file using `subprocess.check_output`, it doesn't get anything:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["bin/test", "--help"],  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
''
>>> subprocess.check_output(["bin/test", "--version"],  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
''
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Python version:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.1+
```

I need to get the script output in tests. How should I do that?

Comment: I do not know if this is the cause, but there shouldn't be a space before --help and --version

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've checked that - there is no difference, regardless the spaces the output is still empty. I've also removed the spaces in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `shell=True`, don't pass the program and its arguments as a list. This works:

```
subprocess.check_output("bin/test --help",  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Edit: of course, leaving `shell` as `False` would have worked too.

Edit2: the documentation explains why

> On Unix, with *shell=True*: If *args* is a string, it specifies the
>   command string to execute through the shell. This means that the
>   string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the
>   shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash
>   escaping filenames with spaces in them. If *args* is a sequence, the
>   first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will
>   be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.