# subprocess.stdout behaves differently with shell=True and shell=False

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script called class.py with one line:

class.py:

```
print "Hello World"
```

I run it in a subprocess, like this.

run_subprocess.py:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "class.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
a = p.communicate()

print a
```

When I run this (on a Mac), I get an empty command string:

```
$ python run_subprocess.py
('', None)
```

When I run this with shell=False, I get the contents of stdout:

run_subprocess.py:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "class.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
a = p.communicate()

print a


$ python run_subprocess.py
('hello world\n', None)
```

Why? How can I get the contents of `stdout` when running subprocess with `shell=True`?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `Popen` is interpreted in a different way depending on the value of `shell`. You need to pass the command and its arguments in a different way. Please, read the documentation (I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095733/getting-output-from-python-script-in-python-tests/9096104#9096104) a couple of days ago).